# How to join two columns and use like clause for joined columns?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

Currently I'm making a search page with CodeIgniter. The problem I'm facing is that I have two columns in my `products` table, `brand` and `model`. I'm trying to select the results based on the query which has three states as shown:

query contains only brand
query contains only model
query contains both

The first two queries work fine, but the problem is when the query contains both the `brand` and `model`. How can I use the LIKE clause for both `brand` and `model` joined columns?

Comment: fulltext indexes would save you?

Comment: @Nemoden explain a bit.

Comment: [fulltext indexes](http://bit.ly/13tyHP7)

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply trying to find rows that contain both a specific brand and a specific model, you can just use two like statements in your where clause:

`select * from products where model like '%MODEL%' and brand like '%BRAND%'`

Answer (score 0):

For flexible querying, you are better off using the CodeIgniter active record class:

```
$this->db->like('model', 'model');
$this->db->like('brand', 'brand');
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->get('products');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if(!empty($brandsearchtext)){
    $this->db->like('p.brand', $this->db->escape_like_str($brandsearchtext));
}
if(!empty($modelsearchtext)){
    $this->db->like('p.model', $this->db->escape_like_str($modelsearchtext));
}

$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from('products');

$result = $this->db->get();
//echo $this->db->last_query();
```